# How to disable Migration Verification during every DbContext initialization

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am using CodeFirst approach in Entity Framework 6 and running my migration script manually to create Db and later update the changes in the schema.

I have noticed that every time the **context is initialized**, it checks for the "**INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES**" and "**MigrationHistory**" metadata in the database. ***That adds 2 additional queries for each call***.

This may not be a desirable situation for production environment. Is there a way to set it only once during application startup and these 2 process does not executed every time the DbContext is initialized.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `null` initializer?

Comment: @cincura.net I used that and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen http://romiller.com/2014/06/10/reducing-code-first-database-chatter/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it the following way and wish to share the solution:

```
class MyCustomDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
        {
        public MyCustomDbConfiguration()
            {
            SetDatabaseInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<MyDbContext>());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Per the EF team, the initializer should only be running once. Doesn't this change mean you aren't using migrations?