# Disable EF Core Migration verification query

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-application-insights

I'm running an asp.net core 2.1.4 web application with entity framework core 2.1.4 using code first. The migration and seed are done on application startup.

I've noticed a couple of EF queries checking for checking the migration history on every call:

```
Executed DbCommand (47ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');

Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');

Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion] FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] ORDER BY [MigrationId];

No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
```

I don't want to check the database on every call. So I changed the ServiceLifetime.Singleton. But still I see this verification queries on every call.

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString,
        builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
}, ServiceLifetime.Singleton, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

There is a similar question on EF6: [How to disable Migration Verification during every DbContext initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220344/how-to-disable-migration-verification-during-every-dbcontext-initialization)

The NullDatabaseInitializer doesn't exist in EF core.

What is recommended to do? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: The default behavior of EF Core is to do nothing (the equivalent of EF6 NullDatabaseInitializer). There must be some application code calling `Database.Migrate` or similar.

Comment: Exactly, I'm calling the `Database.Migrate()` myself on application startup. But the verification queries are done on every new http request.

Comment: Nope. There must be some code of yours (or the libraries other than EF Core you use) which is doing that. EF Core doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! Maybe `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` or `IdentityServer4` is causing this issue.  `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/778

After using a "real" SQL profiler I found out it was working as expected like @Ivan-Stoev said. The requests on my side were somehow using the same operation_id. So the traces and dependencies that where shown to me by application insights where actually not related.

I fixed it by removing the default DependecyTracking of AI.

```
private void RemoveDefaultAiDependencyTracking(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var serviceDescriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ImplementationType == typeof(DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule));
    services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);
}
```

Thanks for you time and sorry for wasting it..